# yii2 change default page

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I'm using rest api of yii2 for my service ajax requests, so I reserved index.php for my project page and I serve yii2 requests on rest.php page.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . rest.php
```

But I also need some of gui, for example, for code generation. How can I see basic application home page at .../rest.php address? Now it returns 404 status while all requests to controllers through it work fine.

Comment: what about having a different module with its own configs to handle REST without interfering with your app web configs like it is done [here](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template) ?

Comment: try building api folder seperatly.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it if it is better solution